# Error: Class does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Tags: c#, class, oop

I'm having a problem with my class's Constructor function.
I have a class called DASHBOARD which inherits from it's base class LINKS.

```
public class Link
{
    private Page aPage;

    public Page myPage
    {
        get { return aPage; }
        set { aPage = value; }
    }
    public Link(int buildingID, Page mypage)
    {
        myPage = mypage;
    }
}


public class Dashboard : Link
{
    private int abuildingid;
    private int acustomerid;

    public int BuildingID
    {
        get { return abuildingid; }
        set { abuildingid = value; }
    }
    public int CustomerID
    {
        get { return acustomerid; }
        set { acustomerid = value; }
    }


    public Dashboard(int buildingid, int customerid, Page mypage)
        : base(buildingid, mypage)
    {
        BuildingID = buildingid;
        CustomerID = customerid;
    }
```

When I write in my code

> new Dashboard(buildingID, customerID, this)

I get an error: **Error 14: 'Dashboard' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is 'this' ? My guess is 'this' is not an instance of Page.

Comment: Your code compiles fine.  Are you sure you don't have multiple classes named Dashboard and it's resolving the wrong one?  Or perhaps you have the code which gives the error in a different project than where you are defining your Dashboard class and it's not referencing the most recent version of the assembly?  This can happen due to a build error or a hard reference to a DLL instead of a project reference.

Comment: @StealthRabbi I'm pretty sure the error would be `cannot convert from TypeA to 'Page'` if that were the case.

Comment: @StealthRabbi this is an instance of page.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I noticed you don't do anything with buildingID in Link's constructor.

Comment: @peer It is not a duplicate at all.

Comment: @peer Note `public Dashboard(int buildingid, int customerid, Page mypage)`

Comment: @TrevorElliott it's interesting what you're saying. I just don't understand it fully. What does it mean that I have an error someplace else but getting referenced here?

Comment: I guess you have multiple classes which are called dashboard, you should refer the correct one. Link is also a strange class name to use. Think of something more usefull.

Comment: @Diane2 Are the class `Dashboard` and the line of code that gives the error in question in two different projects?

Comment: no. I'm only working in one project with one class dashboard.

Comment: Interesting to note, sometimes my code builds but sometimes it refuses and throws ths error.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980741/c-sharp-constructor-has-2-arguments-but-claims-it-does-not-have-a-constructor-t

Comment: When you get this error are you getting ONLY this error, or also other errors?  If you are getting other errors at the same time they could be the root problem.

Comment: @TrevorElliott When I hover over the error it gives me this: The type 'Dashboard' in 'C:\Users...\Temp\...cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Dashboard' in 'C:\Users...\Temp\...dll'.

Comment: It sounds like your project is referencing the output of itself.  Did you add project references to any files?  Remove any non-system references in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: It's either that or you have defined the `Dashboard` class twice in your code somewhere.

Comment: I have a web reference that I use.

Comment: @Diane2 Is that an actual service reference added with Add Service Reference?  A service reference will auto-generate code for you.  Perhaps it created a class named Dashboard?  If that is the case you need to pick another name for your Dashboard class or remove and re-add the service reference and choose a different namespace for it to exist.

Comment: Got it! Gonna put it as an answer. Thanks Trevor Elliot for leading me to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I had a page called Dashboard.aspx. So the two class names were getting mixed up without me realizing it.

That's why sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't.

Thanks everyone for your comments. 3 cheers for Trevor Elliot.